# Open website on machine

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, canvas

I have a rails application with some nice javascript-canvas charts.

I would like to save this charts as images as well.

For this **I have to open the Website** and then javascript, will post the content of the canvas to one of my controller where I do:

```
data = params[:data_uri]
image_data = Base64.decode64(data['data:image/png;base64,'.length .. -1])

  File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/somefilename.png", 'wb') do |f|
    f.write image_data
  end
```

Here is a article on how to do this: http://rohitrox.github.io/2013/07/19/canvas-images-and-rails/

---

**My question is:** Is it possible to automatically let my Rails application open this website and run the javascript?
**How would you do it?** Thanks!

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phantomjs (a headless browser) http://phantomjs.org/ works well for tasks like this.